# Prove that $MD$ passes through the midpoint of $IE$.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image]

> $E$ is the midpoint of line segments $BC$. $F$ is the reflection of $E$ in $(A, B, C)$. $EF \cap (A, B, C) = M$. $I$ is the incentre of $\triangle{ABC}$. $AF \cap (A, B, C) = G$, $GI \cap (A, B, C) = D$ ($D \not\equiv G \not\equiv A$). Prove that $MD$ passes through the midpoint of $IE$.

I have tried many things but all of them didn't work. Right now I don't have any great approaches to this problem.

Comment: Thanks for that. Could you solve the problem?

Comment: Still, thanks for reminding me! It's one of those problems that even our teacher didn't encourage us to try too hard to solve.

Comment: What have you tried? Were you able to prove something new other than that in the given?

Comment: It's a shame that I left my textbooks at school, accidentally.

Comment: Maybe my lack of knowledge, but what is meant with "$F$ is the reflection of $E$ in $(A,B,C)$"? Is it simply that $EF$ is perpendicular to $BC$? Or does it also imply that the distance $EF$ is somehow fixed? In case the distance $EF$ is not fixed, the claim is wrong, so it will be impossible to prove.

Comment: Let the centre of $(A, B, C)$ be $O$. That means $OE \cdot OF = r^2$.

Comment: Yup. That's correct.

Comment: That is going to be hard (with the extensive length of the figure that is drawn).

Comment: So we are trying to prove that $EM \cdot JD = JM \cdot ID$, right?

Comment: There's one detail that I deleted because I assumed that "it is not important". That is "Let $MN$ be the diameter of $(A, B, C)$".

Comment: I was going to tell you that maybe drawing the center and the radii $OB$ and $OC$ and the tangents or diameter that you have might help a bit more. If you like, add another similar figure drawing what I just mentioned and maybe removing the lines joining $A$ with $G$ and $I$ with $D$ for example, for the new figure to be not so much mess. I think it will help you and the MSE community to solve the problem a bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claim 1. $AE$ and $AF$ are symmetric with respect to $AI$.

Proof. Let $O$ be the circumcenter of $ABC$. By definition of $F$, $OE \cdot OF = OA^2$. Hence $\triangle OEA \sim \triangle OAF$. It follows that $\angle EAO = \angle OFA$. Hence 
$$\angle FAM = \angle OMA - \angle MFA = \angle MAO - \angle EAO = \angle MAE.$$

[image]

Claim 2. $\dfrac{BG}{CG}=\dfrac{BA}{CA}$.

Proof. By Claim 1., $\angle BAG = \angle EAC$. Also, $\angle AGB = \angle ACE$. Hence $\triangle ABG \sim \triangle AEC$. Similarly $\triangle GAC \sim \triangle BAE$. It follows that

$$\frac{AB}{BG} = \frac{AE}{EC} = \frac{AE}{EB} = \frac{AC}{CG},$$
so $\dfrac{BG}{CG}=\dfrac{BA}{CA}$.

[image]

Claim 3. Let $BI$, $CI$ intersect the circumcircle of $ABC$ at $X$, $Y$, respectively. Then 
$$\frac{XD}{YD}=\frac{XM}{YM}.$$

Proof. Since $\triangle BIG \sim \triangle DIX$, we have
$$\frac{BG}{BI} = \frac{XD}{DI}.$$
Analogously,
$$\frac{CG}{CI} = \frac{YD}{DI}.$$
Hence 
$$\frac{XD}{YD}=\frac{BG}{CG} \cdot \frac{CI}{BI}.$$
Analogously
$$\frac{XM}{YM}=\frac{BA}{CA} \cdot \frac{CI}{BI}.$$
But by Claim 2. we have $\dfrac{BG}{CG}=\dfrac{BA}{CA}$, so
$$\frac{XD}{YD}=\frac{BG}{CG} \cdot \frac{CI}{BI}=\frac{BA}{CA} \cdot \frac{CI}{BI} = \frac{XM}{YM}.$$

[image]

Claim 4. $MX$ and $MY$ bisect the segments $CI$, $BI$, respectively.

Proof. By Trefoil Lemma, $XI=CI$ and $MI=CI$. Hence $MX$ is perpendicular bisector of $CI$, hence it bisects $CI$. Analogously, $MY$ bisects $BI$.

[image]

Claim 5. Let $K$, $L$ be the midpoints of $CI$, $BI$. Let $DM$ instersect $KL$ at $Z$. Then $Z$ is the midpoint of $KL$.

Proof. Let $\ell$ be the tangent to the circumcircle of $ABC$ at $M$. Then $\angle MYD = \angle(\ell, MD) = \angle(KL, MD) = \angle LZM$. Hence $\triangle MYD \sim \triangle MZL$. Analogously, $\triangle MXD \sim \triangle MZK$. It follows that
$$\frac{MZ}{ZL} = \frac{MY}{YD} = \frac{MX}{XD} = \frac{MZ}{ZK},$$
so $ZL=ZK$.

[image]

Claim 6. $Z$ is the midpoint of $IE$.

Proof. $KILE$ is a parallelogram since $E,K,L$ are the midpoints of $BC$, $CI$, $IB$. Hence midpoints of $KL$, $IE$ coincide. Hence the claim.

[image]

The problem is solved by Claim 6.

---

The following is a solution using projective geometry.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be the midpoints of arcs $AC$, $AB$ of the circumcircle of $ABC$. Then $X$ lies of $BI$ and $Y$ lies on $CI$. Moreover, due to well-known trefoil lemma, $MB=MI=MC$, $XC=XI$ and $YB=YI$. Hence $XM$ and $YM$ intersect $CI$ and $BI$ at their midpoints $K$ and $L$, respectively.

Using well-known properties of symmedians we see that $(AGBC)=-1$.

It is well-known that given a circle $\omega$ and a point $P$, the map $\phi \colon \omega \to \omega$ assigning to a point $T$ the unique point $T'\in \omega$ such that $T,P,T'$ are collinear is projective. Taking as $\omega$ the circumcircle of $ABC$ and $I$ as a $P$ we get that 
$$-1=(AGBC)=(\phi(A)\phi(G)\phi(B)\phi(C))=(MDXY).$$ 
Projecting $\omega$ through $M$ to the line $KL$ we obtain 
$$-1=(MDXY)=(\infty ZKL).$$ where $\infty$ is the point at infinity of the line $KL$ and $Z$ is the intersection of $KL$ with $DM$. This means that $Z$ is the midpoint of $KL$.

But $E,K,L$ are the midpoints of $IBC$, so $IKEL$ is a parallelogram, hence $Z$ is a midpoint of $IE$. We are done!

Comment: Please note that I am a 9th-grade student, so there will be something I will not understand. Could you please explain more about it?

Comment: @LêThànhĐạt sure, what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: This is going to sound really bad for your solution. I haven't studied projective geometry yet. Looking forward to it though.

Comment: OK then, I'll rewrite the solution so that it does not use projective geometry.

Comment: Thanks for your dedication.

Comment: @LêThànhĐạt Please see my updated answer. It only uses similarity of triangles and some easy angle chasing. I hope everything is clear now.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. I was suspicious at first. I was thinking: "Well, this isn't going anywhere." But then the solution unfolded thanks to your claims and proofs in an organizing way. (And you use figures for every step.)